# LUA - how to loop less times than entries in a table?

Tags: loops, lua

LUA neewb having trouble with all the different ways of looping.

I adjusted a template script for mapping audio files in my filesystem to an audio sampler software, where each audio file goes into 1 group --> zone --> file.
This works as intended but now for a "Lite-Version" package of the software I only need some of the samples from my computer and this is where I'm having problems with my loop functions.

This is the function causing issues:
for index, file in next, samples do
...

The table "samples" consists of 180 samples but I'm only creating 38 groups and zones in the audio software for putting audio files into, so obviously this returns an error.

ERROR:
" ...- PATH.LINE: bad argument #2 to '--index' (invalid index, size is 58 got 58)"
The 58 makes sense because it is 38 sample groups + 18 empty groups + 2 template groups that get duplicated.
Since that is still smaller than 180 it wants to keep going and I'm not sure how to tell it to stop there.

CODE:

```
local samples = {}
local root = 0

-- [[ FILE SYSTEM]]
    local i = 1
    for _,p in filesystem.directoryRecursive(folderPath) do
        if filesystem.isRegularFile(p) then
          if filesystem.extension(p) == '.wav' or filesystem.extension(p) == '.aif' or filesystem.extension(p) == '.aiff' then
            samples[i] = p
            i = i+1
          end
        end
    end
```

After this I create the amount of groups I need in the audio software (38).
A group contains a zone which contains a sample

```
-- [[ ZONES & FILES ]]

    -- Create zones and place one file in each of the created groups.
    -- file is a string property of the object Zones
    -- samples is a table, populated with paths to our samples

    for index, file in next, samples do
        -- Initialize the zone variable.
        local z = Zone()
    
        -- Add a zone for each sample.
        instrument.groups[index +1].zones:add(z)
    
        -- Populate the attached zone with a sample from our table.
        z.file = file

        -- detect and set root note
        local detectedPitch = mir.detectPitch(index)
        z.rootKey = math.floor(detectedPitch + 0.5)
    end
```

So my question is: how do I loop through the table samples but only do it up to 38 and not to 180?
I could do

```
for index = 1, #NUM_FACT_LAYERS do
```

but what do I do about file then?
Samples only has the paths to the files but z.file needs the string of the file.
z.file = file won't work in this case.
I guess that's why the previous script used for for in

Comment: `for index = 1, #instrument.groups do`is the solutions I have in mind, does it fit?

Comment: I don't think so. I edited the post  with your suggestion though

Comment: What is "the string of the file"?

Comment: The file name instead of just the path

Comment: Is samples an array? Why would `samples[index]` not work in this case?

Comment: Samples is a table and when I try what you suggest so:
z.file = samples[index]
local detectedPitch = mir.detectPitch(index)

then it says detectPitch expects a string and instead of index

Comment: Hmm. Where is `detectedPitch`? The origin of my confusion is that `for index, file in next, samples do` is equivalent to `for index, file in ipairs(samples) do` is equivalent to `for index = 1, #samples do local file = samples[index]`. Why do you pass the index to detectedPitch? Did you pass the index previously too? Shouldn't detectedPitch receive `file`?

Comment: Whoops my apologies, it wasn't added in the question as I didn't think it would be relevant. Added it now.

Yes detectedPitch should receive file since file has the file name.
The way I understand it the point of "for index, file in next, samples do" is to match up each index with a number, path and file name and if I do "for index = 1, constant do" then I don't see how I can get the correct file name of each path

Comment: Ahh, there might be the confusion, no it does not. Next returns the next index and value, it does not "match each index with a number". Index really is the index of file. That's why my three approaches from above are equivalent. Maybe I'm completely missing the point here, but try again with the new approach and pass `z.file` to `detectedPitch`

Comment: You are correct! Passing z.file to detectPitch worked like a charm. 
For some reason I didn't think it would.
I knew it had to be a simple solution. I'm just unfamiliar with this language and how things work in it.
Thanks for the help!